# check if has class and check if is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){      
        if($('.shoppers-images ul li').hasClass('selected2') && $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a').data('clicked')){
             $('.content-register').show(1000);
                return true;
        }
        });
```

what em i trying to do is check if `$('.shoppers-images ul li')` has a class of "selected2" AND the second element has been clicked... so i can then go on with my code..

Any suggestions? thanks

this is where i add my class:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.shoppers-images ul li').click(function () {
                $('.shoppers-images ul li').removeClass('selected2');
                $(this).addClass('selected2');
            });
        });


resolved code!

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a.selected').addClass('default');
        $('.shoppers-images ul li').click(function () {
            $('.shoppers-images ul li').removeClass('selected2');
            $(this).addClass('selected2');
            if($('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a.selected').hasClass('default') === false)
            {
               $('.shoppers-images ul li').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('selected2')){
                    $('.content-register').show(1000);
                 }
                });
            }
        });
        $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a').click(function(){
            $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a.default').removeClass('default');
            var countrySect = $('#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span').text(); 
            $('.register-state div.jqTransformSelectWrapper span').html(countrySect);

            $('.shoppers-images ul li').each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('selected2')){
                    $('.content-register').show(1000);
            }
        });
      });
     });
```

Comment: To be clear : by "element has been clicked", you mean the element came with the data attribute "clicked", you don't refer to a user interaction ?

Comment: The selector `.shoppers-images ul li` is referring to multiple elements. Should any or all elements have the CSS class?

Comment: Do those selectors match a single element each or multiple elements? Can you include the HTML structure for the relevant section of your page?

Comment: check out the code.. i've resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#the-selector div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.shoppers-images ul li').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('selected2')){
          // do something
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried this! but it works one way! meaning if  has class and then click it works.. but if click and then set class it doesn't work